# Trouble making mypy and phonenumbers module work, implementation missing

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I installed python's [`phonenumbers>=3.12.32`](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/), which should include the stub files, but when I run `mypy` it yields:

```
$ mypy -m module 
module.py:22: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "phonenumbers"
module.py:22: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
```

---

I would guess that either I'm not configuring correctly mypy, because when checking the [project, the `*.pyi` files are there](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/tree/dev/python/phonenumbers), also when checking the installation of the `phonenumbers` module `venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/phonenumbers`, I see that the `*.pyi` files are present.

Any thoughts on how to make it work?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're using `mypy` from the same environment where `phohenumbers` is installed? Please check `which mypy` and `mypy --version`. Also, does this happen with other typed packages from the same venv?

Comment: It could have been something like that. I tried it again in a "fresh" terminal, and It had no issues... Which honestly is just weird.

The env in which it manifested the error, was the same env in which I defined the pyproyect file and executed `venv` and `pip install '.[tests]'`.

Comment: So, can we close this as "not reproducible", since it depends on your one specific environment configuration?